# $_FILES array is empty in php with multiple forms on one html page

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I have an html page with multiple forms on it. I created an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nteuscher/ht7334p6/

```
<table border="2">
<tr>
  <form action="" method="post">
<td colspan="7" align="left"><input type="hidden" 
        name="action" value="Edit">
<input type="submit" value="Edit Profile">
    </td>
  </form>
</tr>
<tr>
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <td> 
  <div class="upload">
   <label for="upload">File: <input type="file" 
           id="upload" name="upload"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="upload">
   <input type="hidden" name="uploadaction" value="ypt">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  </div>
 </td>
 </form>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I have 2 different forms on the page, the $_FILES variable is empty when someone clicks the "Upload" button. If have only the file upload form on the page, the $_FILES variable works as expected and contains all of the necessary information. I verified this by doing a var_dump($_FILES) using my php controller file.

I have checked the php.ini file to make sure that uploads are working, and I as noted, if I remove all forms except the one for file uploads, then everything works as expected.

Any suggestions on how to manage this? I could create a separate page, but I would rather allow uploads directly from this one page.

Comment: The code seems to work fine. Maybe something is clearing the $_FILES before You are displaying it.

Comment: add names to the submit inputs and then on the processing file add `var_dump($_POST)`, just to make sure that the upload form is the one submitted.

Comment: The two submits are handled differently by the controller and I get the following when I do var_dump($_FILES); var_dump($_POST):
array(0) { } 
array(4) { ["upload"]=> string(20) "2013AM_500x150R2.jpg" ["uploadaction"]=> string(3) "ypt" ["id"]=> string(2) "28" ["name"]=> string(14) "Counselor-John" }

So the submit is working properly, but the $_FILES is empty ... I think Michal is on to something ... now I just have to track down where $_FILES might be getting cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had some bad html formatting in the page with another `<form>` without the closing `</form>`. That caused this form to not submit properly. Thank you everyone for the help!